# mov al, BYTE PTR _var[eax] explanation

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Like the title says: Can you explain what `mov  al, BYTE PTR _var[eax]` does?
I suppose it does something like `var[i]` in C, but I'm used to access arrays with something like `mov al, [ebx + eax]`. Maybe this is something MASM specific?

Comment: Yes, it's masm specific. More conventionally, that is written as `mov al, [_var + eax]`.

Comment: @Jester: you should make a true anwser :)